# How do I make MKAnnotations move smoothly over the map (adjust their coordinates)?

Tags: ios, json, swift, gps, mkannotation

I'm a novice Swift developer, and I'm building an app that tracks the location of city buses on a map.

**The problem I have, is I want MKAnnotations to move smoothly between GPS positions (from old one to the one in the fresh JSON), instead of getting deleted and reappearing.**

So far, my app is retrieving a JSON, that gets decoded into an array of objects obeying the MKAnnotation protocol.

Then I display them all on the map with this method:

```
func updateUI(json: MyModelClass) {
    mapView.removeAnnotations(mapView.annotations)
    mapView.addAnnotations(json.busArray)
}
```

The JSON gets downloaded every 10 seconds, and triggers the `updateUI` method, removing existing MKAnnotations and adding fresh ones.

I would be very grateful for any advice.

In case it's needed, here's the model:

```
struct MyModelClass: Codable {
    let busArray: [Bus]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case busArray = "result"
    }

    init(busArray: [Bus]) {
        self.busArray = busArray
    }
}

class Bus: NSObject, Codable, MKAnnotation {
    let latitude, longitude: Double
    let time, title, brigade: String?
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 52.22977, longitude: 21.01178)

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case latitude = "Lat"
        case longitude = "Lon"
        case time = "Time"
        case title = "Lines"
        case brigade = "Brigade"
    }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        self.latitude = try container.decode(Double.self, forKey: .latitude)
        self.longitude = try container.decode(Double.self, forKey: .longitude)
        self.title = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .title)
        self.time = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .time)
        self.brigade = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .brigade)
        self.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(latitude), longitude: CLLocationDegrees(longitude))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add an busID field to the Bus class. To add the busses to the map I would create a method that specifically adds new busses. And you updateUI method you should use a for loop (or equivalent) to match the busID and amend its new location.

I hope this steers you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I ended up doing. I added a busID field, created by combining the line and brigade strings, which produces a unique string for each bus. Then I used a for loop that matches the busID's and updates the coordinates (I know it's not very efficient as it iterates over every object, not ruling out the matched ones, but that's something for another time).

Comment: @MarcinGalus glade I could be of assistance.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

[image]

MKAnnotationView inherits from UIView.

I did this by **not** adding the annotationView as annotation to the `MapView`.

Instead, I did something like

```
mapView.addSubview(annotaionView)
```

After this, use one of iOS´ ways to animate `UIViews`:

The simplest way is to use `UIView.animate{ }`

In the example above, I used `UIKit dynamics` and SnapBehaviour, see https://www.raywenderlich.com/2326-uikit-dynamics-tutorial-getting-started

One thing you need, is to convert map coordinates into `UIView` coordinates:

```
 var snapTo = mapView.convert(cdPOI.coordinate, toPointTo: mapView)
```

after the animation is done, I remove the annotation as subview and do something like `mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)`

Comment: Thank you, that's very useful! Although I first needed a way to match the coordinates with respective Bus objects (OverD's answer helped me with that), your answer shows me how to make the coordinate change even better. I wish I could choose two best answers.

Comment: You can award all answers (a bit) by clicking the upward triangle of all answers you like or helped you.

Comment: I did that, although unfortunately votes from users with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but not publicly displayed...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a snippet of code I wrote based on OverD's answer. The value of `subtitle` is the same as busID.

```
DispatchQueue.global().async {

                for old in self.mapView.annotations {
                    for new in model.busArray {
                        if new.busID == old.subtitle {
                            if let annotation = old as? Bus {
                                DispatchQueue.main.async {                          
                                    annotation.coordinate = new.coordinate
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
```

**EDIT - Refactored and made the annotationView move smoothly from old coordinate to the new one.**

```
func matchIDs(mapView: MKMapView, annotations: [MKAnnotation], model: MyModel) {

        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            for annotation in annotations {
                if let filteredBus = model.busArray.filter({ $0.busID == annotation.subtitle }).first {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {

                        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
                            let matchedBus = annotation
                            if let annotationForView = mapView.view(for: matchedBus)?.annotation as? Bus {
                                annotationForView.coordinate = filteredBus.coordinate
                            }
                        })

                    }
                } else {
                    // do nothing
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**I also implemented a `viewFor annotation` method in my MKMapView delegate (View Controller) that creates a custom icon for every annotation.**

Comment: You could refactor this to avoid the pyramid of doom, I will add some sample code to my answer when I am near a computer